# How to draw the right angle symbol (square) with a dot in the center?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

I'm trying to reproduce the following picture.

[image: right-angle with dot in center]

I've already searched, but I don't find with the dot in the center, and I have to reproduce this notation many times.

EDIT: here is what I got until now

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,3);
\coordinate (D) at ($(C)!(A)!(B)$);
\draw (A)node[below left]{$A$}--(B)node[below right]{$B$}--(C)node[above left]{$C$}--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (A)--(D)node[above right]{$D$};
%I didn't tried the right angle because of the dot
\end{tikzpicture}
```

EDIT2: here in Brasil we use this notation for right angles, not the empty rectangle

Comment: Instead of posting just an image can you post the code (in a compilable document) that you have to produce most of the image without the dot, and then people can help you with the dot.

Comment: the problem is not exatly the dot, but the right angle symbol, whose difference is the dot. I'll edit the main post

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen a right angle symbol drawn like that, though it certainly makes sense that way. It has always been a quarter circle with a dot for me.

Comment: Though it's an old question: you can find it in the pgf-manual, Libraries, Angles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your own `\dotMarkRightAngle` as below. Four parameters need to be entered; size of the angle (square side) and three coordinates in parentheses `(#2,#3,#4)` taken clock-wise.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\def\dotMarkRightAngle[size=#1](#2,#3,#4){%
 \draw ($(#3)!#1!(#2)$) -- 
       ($($(#3)!#1!(#2)$)!#1!90:(#2)$) --
       ($(#3)!#1!(#4)$);
 \path (#3) --node[circle,fill,inner sep=.5pt]{} ($($(#3)!#1!(#2)$)!#1!90:(#2)$);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,3);
\coordinate (D) at ($(C)!(A)!(B)$);
\draw (A)node[below left]{$A$}--(B)node[below right]{$B$}--(C)node[above left]{$C$}--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (A)--(D)node[above right]{$D$};
\dotMarkRightAngle[size=6pt](B,A,C);
\dotMarkRightAngle[size=6pt](A,D,B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, with `tkz-euclide` and using `\tkzMarkRightAngle` and `\tkzLabelAngle`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,3);
\coordinate (D) at ($(C)!(A)!(B)$);
\draw (A)node[below left]{$A$}--(B)node[below right]{$B$}--(C)node[above left]{$C$}--cycle;
\draw[dashed,draw=gray] (A)--(D)node[above right]{$D$};

\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,A,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.15](C,A,B){$\cdot$}

\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,D,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.15](A,D,B){$\cdot$}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice! to be better could have an option to change the marker square size too? EDIT: wait, I must read it again.

Comment: Perfect, first I thought the size parameter refered to the dot, not to the square side.

Comment: usetkzobj{all} ? which version of tkz-euclide are you using? I removed this option a long time ago!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

pure tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dotbox/.style = {draw, minimum size=3mm,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                 anchor=#1,
                 label=center:$\cdot$},
node distance = 0pt
                    ]
\coordinate[label=below  left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$B$] (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate[label=above  left:$C$] (C) at (0,3);
\coordinate[label=above right:$D$] (D) at ($(C)!(A)!(B)$);
\draw (A) --(B) --(C) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (A)--(D);
% angles
\node[dotbox=south west] at (A) {} ;
\path (D) -- node[pos=0,sloped,dotbox=north east] {} (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late for this ;-) but in case it may interest someone, here is a way of producing a right angle symbol with MetaPost (with the required dot inside), heavily inspired by the macro designed by André Heck in his [MetaPost tutorial](https://staff.science.uva.nl/a.j.p.heck/Courses/mptut.pdf), p. 47-48.

Notice that the `turningnumber` of the path (1 if counter-clockwise, -1 if not) ensures that the order in which the extremities `endofa` and `endofb` are given doesn't matter: the mark will be the same. Also, the coordinates of point D are not explicitly given, but computed by MetaPost itself via two implicit linear equations.

Included in a LuaLaTeX program, thanks to the `luamplib` package.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    vardef mark_right_angle (expr common, endofa, endofb, mark_size) =
        save tn ; tn := turningnumber(common -- endofa -- endofb -- cycle) ;
        save t; transform t; 
        t = identity 
            zscaled (mark_size*unitvector((1+tn)*endofa + (1-tn)*endofb - 2*common)) 
            shifted common;
        z1 = (1, 0); z2 = (1, 1); z3 = (0, 1);
        save rangle; path rangle; 
        rangle = (origin -- z1 -- z2 -- z3 -- cycle) transformed t; 
        draw (z1 -- z2 -- z3) transformed t;
        drawdot center rangle withpen pencircle scaled 2bp;
    enddef ;
    beginfig(1);
        u = cm; pair A, B, C, D;
        mark_size := 2mm;
        A = origin; B = (4u, 0); C = (0, 3u);
        D = whatever[B,C]; (D-A) dotprod (B-C) = 0;
        label.lft(btex $A$ etex, A); label.rt(btex $B$ etex, B);
        label.lft(btex $C$ etex, C); label.urt(btex $D$ etex, D);
        draw A--B--C--cycle; draw A -- D dashed evenly;
        mark_right_angle(D, A, B, mark_size); 
        mark_right_angle(A, B, C, mark_size);
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I’m a bit late to the party, but while searching for how to mark right angles, I’ve stumbled upon both your post here and the `angles` library from TikZ. This last one makes it very simple to achieve what you’ve asked:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,3);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(C)!(A)!(B)$);
    \draw (A)node[below left]{$A$}--(B)node[below right]{$B$}--(C)node[above left]{$C$}--cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (A)--(D)node[above right]{$D$};
    \pic ["$\cdot$",draw,angle radius=10,angle eccentricity=0.5] {right angle=A--D--B};
    \pic ["$\cdot$",draw,angle radius=10,angle eccentricity=0.5] {right angle=B--A--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course you could define a style to avoid repeating part of the code. Also I’m using the `quotes` library here to type `"$\cdot$"` as the angle label, else the syntax is `pic text=$\cdot$`.

[image: Output of above code]

Answer (score 0):

With tkz-elements and tkz-euclide. For an angle, I've used the German notation. Your notation is not very logical, as the usual notation already shows that the angle is right-angled.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tkz-elements}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tkzelements}
   z.A      = point : new ( 0 , 0 )
   z.B      = point : new ( 4 , 0 )  
   z.C      = z.A   : north (3)
   L.BC     = line  : new ( z.B , z.C )
   z.D      = L.BC  : projection (z.A)
\end{tkzelements}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed,gray](A,D)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,A,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.15](B,A,C){$\cdot$}
%\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,D,B)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[german](A,D,B)
%\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.15](A,D,B){$\cdot$}
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]